# The best way for obtaining the canonical label of a matroid?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, matroid-theory

For a graph, we can canonical labelings with Nauty or other methods. But for a matroid, I do not find an easy way to labeling.

Dillon Mayhewa, Gordon F. Royle introduced the hyperplane graph of a matroid in their paper "Matroids with nine elements", which is the bipartite graph whose vertices are the elements and hyperplanes of the matroid and where a hyperplane-vertex is adjacent to an element-vertex if and only if the hyperplane contains the element. Then we can use Nauty to labelings the bipartite graph. But this method is a bit slow.

So I want to know is there any better method for canonical labeling of a matroid?

Comment: Depending on how your matroid is given, some other hash might be more suitable. How are your matroids given? Maybe relevant: http://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/~bvrr/jour/RS1.pdf

Comment: I find some sagemath codes in "https://oeis.org/A300985/a300985.sage.txt", where use canonical_label of an IncidenceStructure. It's enough for me.